# Arithmetic overflow error (numeric to numeric) with MERGE: SQL Server bug?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a target table `TargetTable` that has a `DECIMAL(20, 7)` column. I also have a source table `SourceTable` that has a `DECIMAL(20, 7)` column, but the values in this table are all integers anyway.

When I try to upsert data into `TargetTable` from `SourceTable` via a `MERGE` statement, I get a standard error.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

I don't really understand why this would happen since both data types are identical.

The weird thing is this, though: when I use a `SELECT INTO` on `TargetTable` to create a test table `TestTable`, then change the target of the merge to `TestTable`, the upsert completes. I also don't understand why this would be the case, since `TargetTable` and `TestTable` are for the most part identical.

Has anyone encountered this before, is this a bug, or is there some obscure nuance of SQL Server that I'm missing?

---

**Sample Code**:

Fails:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT Off
GO

MERGE
    TargetTable Target
USING
    (
        SELECT
            cast(forecast as DECIMAL(20, 7)) forecast
          ,[SegmentID]
          ,[Country]
          ,[Environment]
          ,[YearColumn]
          ,[ForecastYear]
          ,[Criterion]
        FROM
            SourceTable
    ) Source
    ON
    (
        Target.SegmentID = Source.SegmentID
        AND Target.Country = Source.Country
        AND Target.Environment = Source.Environment
        AND Target.YearColumn = Source.YearColumn
        AND Target.ForecastYear = Source.ForecastYear
        AND Target.Criterion = Source.Criterion
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND Source.Forecast <> 0 AND Source.Forecast IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT (SegmentID, Country, Environment, YearColumn, Forecast, ForecastYear, Criterion)
    VALUES (Source.SegmentID, Source.Country, Source.Environment, Source.YearColumn, Source.Forecast, Source.ForecastYear, Source.Criterion)
WHEN MATCHED AND (Source.Forecast = 0 OR Source.Forecast IS NULL) THEN
    DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND Source.Forecast <> Target.Forecast THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Forecast = Source.Forecast;
```

Succeeds:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    TestTable
FROM
    TargetTable
GO

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT Off
GO

MERGE
    TestTable Target
USING
    (
        SELECT
            cast(forecast as DECIMAL(20, 7)) forecast
          ,[SegmentID]
          ,[Country]
          ,[Environment]
          ,[YearColumn]
          ,[ForecastYear]
          ,[Criterion]
        FROM
            SourceTable
    ) Source
    ON
    (
        Target.SegmentID = Source.SegmentID
        AND Target.Country = Source.Country
        AND Target.Environment = Source.Environment
        AND Target.YearColumn = Source.YearColumn
        AND Target.ForecastYear = Source.ForecastYear
        AND Target.Criterion = Source.Criterion
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND Source.Forecast <> 0 AND Source.Forecast IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT (SegmentID, Country, Environment, YearColumn, Forecast, ForecastYear, Criterion)
    VALUES (Source.SegmentID, Source.Country, Source.Environment, Source.YearColumn, Source.Forecast, Source.ForecastYear, Source.Criterion)
WHEN MATCHED AND (Source.Forecast = 0 OR Source.Forecast IS NULL) THEN
    DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND Source.Forecast <> Target.Forecast THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.Forecast = Source.Forecast;
```

Comment: Also, if this sounds more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com than SO, please weigh in.

Comment: Please, post the query you are using so we can help you out

Comment: @Lamak: I didn't think posting the code would be necessary, since this seems like something inconsistent more in principle than in specifics, but I will post the code.

Comment: Why don't you just try to use SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT Off and see what results are getting inserted into target table .This might give you an idea whether there is any loss of data

Comment: @praveen: I did set that, and will include that in the sample code.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on `TargetTable` that may be causing this error?

Comment: @Lamak: You bet I do! Please post this as the answer.

Comment: Glad to see you found the answer, I was going to recommend also looking at defaults and check constraints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code seems to have no error at all. Furthermore, the fact that it works fine when you create another table as the target, using the same structure and data that the original table shows that the error is not there. The most likely reason is that you have a trigger on your original table that is executing a query that fails, and that is the error you are seeing.

Comment: So, in theory, I *didn't* have to post code after all? :) But thanks again for sharing.

Comment: Actually, without looking at your code, I would've never known for sure that there was no error, and that the probably culprit was a trigger

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occur beacuase you can use trigger with that spcific table but that table context or some changes perform in database so it display error this type of error so plzz disable trigger and perform task

Comment: your answer would be improved with a piece of example code demonstrating what you are saying.